# Does PayPal Embedded Payment Flow work with iOS and Android webviews?

Tags: android, ios, paypal, uiwebview, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am developing a native `iOS` and `Android` app that use `PayPal Adaptive Chained` payments.  Right now it uses a webview  (`UIWebView`-iOS and `WebView`-Android) for the PayPal Adaptive stuff.  The problem is that those html pages are not made for mobile and you have to zoom to the content.  I found [Embedded Pay Flow](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-embeddedPayment-curl-etc/) from paypal for Adaptive payments and it offers a lightbox and mini-browser option.  It looks to be more mobile friendly.  Has anyone used this as part of a native iOS or Android app and did it work?

Comment: any updates on this? paypal is really bad at explaining this stuff...